# How to use DBObject Query in distinct function of mongo template?

Tags: mongodb, distinct

i want to find distinct value of a field with some Query criteria. my code is..

```
public List searchservice(String th_type) {

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("th_type").regex(th_type));
    List list = operations.getCollection("doclist").distinct("th_type", query);

    return list;
}
```

in mongo template a distinct function is defined

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection).distinct(key, query)
```

bu my code is giving error because i am using simple Query object instead of DBObject Query. how can i use DBObject Query here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **[BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html)** for this:

```
public List searchservice(String th_type) {    
    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
    dbObject.append("th_type", th_type); 

    DBCollection dBCollection = operations.getCollection("doclist");
    List list = dBCollection.distinct("th_type", dbObject);    

    return list;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With regex:

```
BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject(); 
regexQuery.put("th_type", new BasicDBObject("$regex", th_type)); 
List list = operations.getCollection("doclist").distinct("th_type",regexQuery);
```

Comment: Done ..
   BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    regexQuery.put("th_type",
   new BasicDBObject("$regex", th_type));
  
  List list = operations.getCollection("doclist").distinct("th_type",regexQuery);

Comment: @DeepakPareek Awesome, I have updated my answer to reflect your changes.